# Object Mapper convert json format to object, java

Tags: java, json, data-binding, objectmapper, fasterxml

I have a class:

```
public class Parent{
   private Child child;

}

public class Child{
  String name;
  String surname;
}
```

And I got an info body as a `json` format in two types:

1.

```
   {
    "child"{
      "name":"TOM"
      "surname":"Finn"
            }
    }
```

2. 

```
  {
    "name":"TOM"
    " surname": "Finn"
   }
```

And when I try to do the following:
`Parent parent = objectmapper.convertvalue(body, Parent.class)`

In first type of body it's ok but with second I got error `IllegalArgumentException`.

How can I fix it that both type of body will be accepted?

Comment: well first of all you are not inputting valid json

Comment: I edited my answer, check if it helps you solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a comma in JSON and have space in `surname` string. And `child` must be in brackets too. Try this:

```
{
  "child": {
    "name":"TOM",
    "surname": "Finn"
  }
}
```

Read about JSON formatting. There aren't many rules, but you should stick to them.

EDIT:

If you are sure your JSON is correct, you can focus on your classes.
`ObjectMapper` needs getters or setters to work or instead of you have to change the default configuration using `setVisibility()`.

Second, use the `readValue()` method instead of `convertValue()`.

You can read more about `ObjectMapper` in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not) if you still have a problem to handle it.

Comment: Thanks, I added Getter and Setter.
but the problem is with body , which I get from json. At first time I get Parent object with Child. The second time I got just Child object and I need to add it in to Parent class.

Comment: Ok, so in this case all what you want is change destiny class in mapper. `objectmapper.readValue(body, Child.class)` and with the object of class `Child` obtained, call the constructor of the `Parent` class.